# how much of the DOM is refreshed if I move a small image?

Tags: javascript, image, dom, animation, html

Newbie question: I am making a simple html game. It consists of these DIV layers:

```
z=1: large image (framing image)
z=2: medium image covering z1 (houses, trees)
z=3: small image covering z2 (character)
z=4: semi transparent image covering z3 (foreground objects)
z=5: medium image covering z2 but not z3 (other objects on the scene)
```

If I move the character (layer z3), which parts of the DOM are refreshed? 
I know it depends on the browser, but are there general rules for minimizing the changes?

Comment: If your making a simple game, consider using `<canvas>`

Comment: If you move it by setting `z3.style.left` and `z3.style.top`, I expect one or two page reflows to occur. There is no such thing as a "DOM refresh" btw. The DOM is an object tree - you can set properties of objects inside that tree, but that won't cause the entire tree to recalculate.

Comment: If you mean by moving changing in the CSS properties , like top,left 
,Z-index ....etc , using Javascript , nothing will refresh . 
I suggest you put the small image you want to move in a separate Z-layer , and position=fixed , 
and move it as you want , it won't effect others elements in most browsers

Comment: @Raynos: I considered canvas, but the game is VERY simple, so why limit the number of browsers?

Comment: @xSari3x - thanks, that's good to know. Then a 1 pixel image can be moved at a high frame rate, even though it affects the large semi-transparent image on top?

Comment: @ChrisTolworthy Guess so , give it a try .
I remember I did it before .

Comment: @ChrisTolworthy All current browsers support CANVAS. Avoiding it just to have it work in *older* versions of IE doesn't sound like a good strategy to me. The benefit of writing modern web-applications is far greater...

Comment: @ChrisTolworthy because the amount of effort it takes to support more browsers is just not worth it

Comment: @Šime Vidas - my game is aimed at people who are not web savvy. A large proportion still use IE8 on XP (IE9 only works on Vista and above). Nearly half my market cannot use canvas.

Comment: As an aside to the original question and my answer, including one extra script can make canvas available to older IE versions: http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul Irish did a quick video on how to get this information out of Chrome via its DevTools. It is located at http://paulirish.com/2011/viewing-chromes-paint-cycle/

While all browsers will vary somewhat in what goes on during repainting, this should offer a bit of a foothold.